# Using FlatFileItemReader with a TaskExecutor (Thread Safety)

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, spring-batch, flat-file

There are a lot of examples which use `FlatFileItemReader` along with `TaskExecutor`. I provide samples below (both with XML and Java Config):

- [Using Oracle Coherence with Spring Batch](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/cloudcomp/coherence-springbatch-1400985.html)
- [Spring Batch Multithreading Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/batch/spring-batch-multithreading-example/)

I have used it my self with XML configuration for large CSVs (GB size) writing to database with the out-of-the-box `JpaItemWriter`. There seem to be no issues even without setting save-state = false or taking any kind of special handling.

Now, `FlatFileItemReader` is documented **as not thread-safe**.

My guess was that `JpaItemWriter` was "covering" the issue by persisting Sets i.e. collections with no duplicates if the `hashCode()` and `equals()` were covering the business key of the Entity. However, even this way it is not enough to prevent duplicates due to non-thread safe reading and processing.

Could you please clarify: is it proper/correct/safe to use the out-of-the-box `FlatFileItemReader` within a Tasklet which has assigned a TaskExecutor? Regardless of the Writer. If not, how could we explain in theory the lack of errors when a `JPAItemWriter` is used?

P.S: The example links that I give above, use `FlatFileItemReader` with TaskExecutor without mentioning at all possible thread-safety issues...

Comment: I may be wrong but are you asking how `JpaItemWriter` is thread-safe when `FlatFileItemReader` is not?

Comment: My question is more general. I provide 2 links where a FlatFileItemReader is used with TaskExecutor and different Writers without any special handling for thread safety. Moreover I provided my own experience and I tried to give a theoretical explanation on how a JpaItemWriter could "hide" the problem under some circumstances. So in other words my question is: how should we use it properly and if finally it can work with TaskExecutor as-is.

Comment: Do you mean the `JpaItemReader` or `JpaItemWriter`?

Comment: Sorry if I am was not so explicit. I re-phrase: Is it proper to use the out-of-the-box FlatFileItemReader within a Tasklet which has assigned a TaskExecuror? Regardless of the Writer. If not, how could we explain in theory the lack of errors when a JPAItemWriter is used?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR** It is safe to use a `FlatFileItemReader` with a `TaskExecutor` provided the `Writer` is thread-safe. (Assuming that you are not concerned with restarting jobs, retrying steps, skipping, etc at the moment).

**Update :** There is now a [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2578) that officially confirms that `saveState` needs to be set to `false` (i.e disable restartability) if one wants to use `FlatFileItemReader` with a `TaskExecutor` in a thread safe manner.

---

Let's first hear it from the horses mouth by seeing what  the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) says about using multi-threaded steps with a `TaskExecutor`.

> Spring Batch provides some implementations of ItemWriter and
>   ItemReader. Usually they say in the Javadocs if they are thread safe
>   or not, or what you have to do to avoid problems in a concurrent
>   environment. If there is no information in Javadocs, you can check the
>   implementation to see if there is any state

Let's address your questions now :

> Could you please clarify: is it proper/correct/safe to use the
>   out-of-the-box FlatFileItemReader within a Tasklet which has assigned
>   a TaskExecutor? Regardless of the Writer. If not, how could we explain
>   in theory the lack of errors when a JPAItemWriter is used?

The statement "*Regardess of the writer*" is incorrect. The `Writer` you use must be thread-safe. The [JpaItemWriter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaItemWriter.html) is thread-safe accroding to the *Java* docs and can safely be used with a `FlatFileItemReader` that is not thread-safe. Explaining how `JpaItemWriter` is thread-safe would make this answer long. I recommend that you post another question if you are interested in how specific writers handle thread-safety. (As mentioned by the *Spring Batch* docs as well)

> P.S: The example links that I give above, use FlatFileItemReader with TaskExecutor without mentioning at all possible thread-safety issues..

If you take a look at the coherence example, you will see that they clearly modify the `CoherenceBatchWriter.java` in *Figure 6*. They first make `mapBatch`  local variable so that multiple threads have their own copy of this `Map`. Moreover, if you dig further into the *Coherence* API, you should find that the `NamedCache` being returned would be thread safe.

The second link that you provide looks really dicey since the `Writer` does not do anything to avoid *race conditions*. That example is indeed an incorrect use of a multi-threaded step.

---

Comment: Thank you for all the provided information. However, given the chunk-oriented processing style, if the `FlatFileItemReader` is not thread-safe, isn't it possible different threads to have read the same lines of a file? This way, the Writer (even if it is thread-safe) would attempt to write duplicate items in the end. This is why I didn't put emphasis on the Writer part.

Comment: @kmandalas Yes that's possible but if the writer is thread-safe, this issue is nullified so all is well in the end. If you take a look at the `Writer` implementation for *Cohernece*, you will see that the ensure that there won't be any duplicate writes as the writer writes to a thread-safe `Map` and a `Map` doesn't allow duplicate keys. Also, `JpaItemWriter` is thread-safe and would give you the same quarantine of avoidin duplicate inserts IMO. So the writer does matter even if you did not emphasize on it.