# Why do these threads read the entire file instead of maxitemcounter?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I'm doing a process with Spring Batch multi-thread. My process receives a large txt file (> 100k lines). I want each thread to process X lines of the file and do X process with the information to gain time.

I am using the FlatFileItemRead class passing the initial and final line to each thread. I'm doing tests with 19k lines, 3 and 4 threads and I cannot see why the first thread if it starts and stops in the correct line, but the rest of threads start in the correct line but not end in the correct one, read the file until the end.

I have read many questions about this topic and about the FlatFileItemReader class, it is not thread-safe. I think my problem is here, but I pass saveState to false and I indicate the lines to each thread. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270806/using-flatfileitemreader-with-a-taskexecutor-thread-safety)).

These are the XML configuration files and the RangePartition file (Steps setTiempoInicial and stTiempoFinal only print the initial and total time):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <batch:job id="superTxtTest">

        <batch:step id="setTiempoInicial" next="validacionDePers">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                start-limit="1">
                <batch:chunk reader="tiempoInicialReader" writer="tiempoInicialWriter"
                    commit-interval="1" skip-limit="1">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include
                            class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.PersException" />
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="promotionListener" />
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="validacionDePers" next="setTiempoFinal">
            <partition step="validacionDePersSlave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
                <handler grid-size="3" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
            </partition>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="setTiempoFinal">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                start-limit="1">
                <batch:chunk reader="tiempoFinalReader" writer="tiempoFinalWriter"
                    commit-interval="1" skip-limit="1">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include
                            class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.PersException" />
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>

    </batch:job>

    <batch:step id="validacionDePersSlave">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager"
            start-limit="1">
            <batch:chunk reader="tratamientoPersReader" writer="validacionPersWriter"
                commit-interval="1" skip-limit="1">
                <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                    <batch:include
                        class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.PersException" />
                </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
            </batch:chunk>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

    <bean id="promotionListener"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.listener.ExecutionContextPromotionListener">
        <property name="keys" value="tiempoInicial" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="validacionPersWriter"
        class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.writer.ValidacionPersWriter"
        scope="step">
        <property name="threadName" value="#{stepExecutionContext[name]}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor" />
    <bean id="rangePartitioner"
        class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.partitioner.RangePartitioner" />

    <bean id="tratamientoPersReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
        scope="step">
        <property name="resource"
            value="file:C:\Users\user\Desktop\testFile.txt" />
        <property name="encoding" value="utf8" />
        <property name="lineMapper" ref="ficheroPersMapper" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="#{stepExecutionContext[fromId]}" />
        <property name="maxItemCount" value="#{stepExecutionContext[toId]}" />
        <property name="saveState" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ficheroPersMapper"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
        <property name="fieldSetMapper" ref="ficheroPersSetMapper" />
        <property name="lineTokenizer">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                <property name="delimiter" value=";" />
                <property name="names"
                    value="a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="ficheroPersSetMapper"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper">
        <property name="prototypeBeanName" value="fichero" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="fichero" class="com.testpartitionfile.batch.dto.Fichero"
        scope="prototype" />

</beans>
```

RangePartitioner:

```
public class RangePartitioner implements Partitioner {

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {

        Map<String, ExecutionContext> result = new HashMap<String, ExecutionContext>();

        int range = 1;
        
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\testFile.txt"));
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n') {
                        ++count;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (count != 0) {
                range = (count/gridSize);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
            }
        } 
        
        int fromId = 1;
        int toId = range;

        for (int i = 1; i <= gridSize; i++) {
            ExecutionContext value = new ExecutionContext();

            System.out.println("\nHilo : " + i);
            System.out.println("Index Inicial : " + fromId);
            System.out.println("Index Final : " + toId + "\n");

            value.putInt("fromId", fromId - 1);
            value.putInt("toId", toId);

            // give each thread a name, thread 1,2,3
            value.putString("name", "Hilo " + i);

            result.put("partition" + i, value);

            fromId = toId + 1;
            toId += range;
            if (i == gridSize - 1) toId = toId + 1;

        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Initial Log with 3 threads:

```
Thread: 1
Initial Index: 1
Final Index: 6333


Thread: 2
Index Initial: 6334
Final Index: 12666


Thread: 3
Index Initial: 12667
Final Index: 19000
```

**Case 1:**

Thread 1 reads up to 6333. Thread 2 reads up to 19000 instead of reading up to 12666 and thread 3 reads up to 19000.

**Case 2:**

With 4 threads the threads 2 and 3 read up to 19000.

Why thread 2 in case 1 and threads 2 and 3 in case 2 read from initial line (correct) to the end (incorrect)?

**Update 25/07/2021**

Issue is open in: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/805

Comment: I was able to reproduce the case (see [this repo](https://github.com/benas/sandbox/blob/master/so55227133/output.txt)). However, I can't see why the second thread is not respecting the `maxItemCount`. I need to dig deeper to investigate what's happening behind the scene. In the meantime, if you didn't find an answer and believe it is a bug, please open a ticket in JIRA and we will plan if for a future release.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Thanks for answering. I have tried to find the reason why isnt respecting the maxitemcounter, but I cannot find it. In the meanwhile, I will try to use other ways to get partitioned, for example, sharing the large file into smaller ones and using multiresource. Could you tell me how I can open a Jira ticket to expose the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here is the JIRA instance for the project: https://jira.spring.io/projects/BATCH. You need to create an account then open a new issue. Please do open an issue only if you are sure it is actually a bug, in which case please provide a failing test. FYI, we are planning to migrate issues from JIRA to github later this year (but that's a plan, not a commitment), so you will be able at some point to open issues directly on github.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine 
It is very difficult to me to know if the problem is a Spring Batch bug or a problem that is causing the concurrency of threads. I dont have much experience debugging multi-thread. I think the multi-thread is well designed but I'm not 100% sure. Could you give me your personal opinion about it?My apologies, but I need much more practice to be able to assess whether it is a Spring Batch bug or not. Thanks.

Comment: As mentioned, I'm not sure neither. I tried to reproduce the case before answering but I don't know yet if this is s bug in spring batch or an issue with your configuration. I will try my best to dig deeper asap. In all cases, you can open an issue in JIRA so that we don't forget to tackle it :-)

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I´ve opened the next ticket: https://jira.spring.io/browse/BATCH-2801

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to multi-threading. I think the problem is that `maxItemCount` should be set to a different value. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score -1):

Skipped lines are not counted when considering whether `maxItemCount` lines have been read.

Instead of calculating the variable `toId` and passing it to `maxItemCount`, you need to pass the fixed value `range` to `maxItemCount`.

edit: As the answer has been down-voted, I've pushed the `RangePartitioner` from the question and a `FixedRangePartitioner` to github. The latter sets `maxItemCount` to `range` and works as expected: https://github.com/hpoettker/so-partitioning